Swagger doesn't return the data
I'm studying Express and I built a simple application that searches the MariaDB database, and returns all the data in JSON. using compression returns 2MB of data, in total there are twelve thousand records. When testing the request and the swagger crashes, the error RESULT_CODE_HUNG occurs. Here is the json used in the configuration
{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "API",
        "description": "API to return database information",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "description": "Server"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/allresults": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "Returns all results from database",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Request succcessfully",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TestData"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "TestData": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "service": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ping": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "download": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "upload": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "comments": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TestDetails"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "scheduled": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "created_at": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time"
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time"
                    }
                }
            },
            "TestDetails": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date-time"
                    },
                    "ping": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PingData"
                    },
                    "download": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DownloadData"
                    },
                    "upload": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/UploadData"
                    },
                    "packetLoss": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "isp": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "interface": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/InterfaceData"
                    },
                    "server": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ServerData"
                    },
                    "result": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ResultData"
                    }
                }
            },
            "PingData": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "jitter": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "latency": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "low": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                }
            },
            "DownloadData": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "bandwidth": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "bytes": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "elapsed": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "latency": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LatencyData"
                    }
                }
            },
            "UploadData": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "bandwidth": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "bytes": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "elapsed": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "latency": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LatencyData"
                    }
                }
            },
            "LatencyData": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "iqm": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "low": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "jitter": {
                        "type": "number"
                    }
                }
            },
            "InterfaceData": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "internalIp": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "ipv4"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "macAddr": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "isVpn": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "externalIp": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "ipv4"
                    }
                }
            },
            "ServerData": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "port": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "ip": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "ipv4"
                    }
                }
            },
            "ResultData": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "uri"
                    },
                    "persisted": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Swagger use in server.js
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDocument))


12k records in a single response seems way too much. Consider implementing pagination for that endpoint to return e.g. 25-100 records at a time.
